# How to scale two timeseries to match cumulative pct change but keep initial values of one of them

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series, scale

I have two timeseries like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 8, 3],
    'B': [10, 33, 22, 39, 30, 66, 34],
})

df.A.plot(color="blue")
df.B.plot(color="orange")
```

[image]

I want to plot them on the same graph to compare them and therefore I need to scale them.
I want to keep the values of A and scale B to the approximate range as A.

So it should look like this (except that I need the original values of A to display them on the y-axis):

```
df.A.pct_change().fillna(0).cumsum().plot(color="blue")
df.B.pct_change().fillna(0).cumsum().plot(color="orange")
```

[image]

I tried e.g. minmax scaling, but that doesn't work (at least how I am doing it):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.A.plot(color="blue", ax=ax)
pd.DataFrame(minmax_scale(X=df.B.values, feature_range=(df.A.min(), df.A.max()))).plot(color="orange", ax=ax)
```

[image]

I also tried e.g. this (but my math doesn't work):

```
df.A.plot(color="blue")
d = df.A.iloc[-1] / df.B.iloc[-1]
(df.B * d).plot(color="orange")
```

[image]

ChatGPT came up with this approach, which goes in the right direction but it's not working either:

```
pca = df.A.pct_change().fillna(0)
pcb = df.B.pct_change().fillna(0)
cpca = (1 + pca).cumprod() - 1
cpcb = (1 + pcb).cumprod() - 1
ratio = cpca.iloc[-1] / cpcb.iloc[-1]
scaled = pd.Series(df.B * ratio)
scaled = scaled.add(df.A.iloc[0]).values
```

How can I achieve this?
I need the actual calculation of how to scale the values of B.
(In fact I am not even using matplotlib, so please don't link answers refering to matplotlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Scale values
df["A_cum_change"] = df["A"].pct_change().fillna(0).cumsum()
df["B_cum_change"] = df["B"].pct_change().fillna(0).cumsum()
reg = LinearRegression().fit(
    df["A_cum_change"].values.reshape(-1, 1), df["A"].values.reshape(-1, 1)
)
df["B_scaled"] = reg.predict(df["B_cum_change"].values.reshape(-1, 1))

df["B_scaled"])
# Output
0    0.684503
1    2.903649
2    2.582034
3    3.327597
4    3.104940
5    4.262755
6    3.794951
Name: B_scaled, dtype: float64
```

```py
# Plot values
values = {col: df[col] for col in ("A", "B_scaled")}
for column, color in zip(values, ("blue", "orange")):
    plt.plot(values[column], color=color, label=column)

plt.legend(loc="upper left")
```

Which outputs in a Jupyter notebook:

[image]

Comment: Thank you but it's not exactly what I need, I didn't express the question clear enough. I need the actual calculation of how to scale the values of df.B, not how to plot it in matplotlib (in fact I am not using matplotlib, but pyqtgraph and the values of df.A. need to stay the same, as they are custom CandlestickItems)

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. There still consists a problem, the values get scaled to df.A.max so I won't be able to tell which graph "performs better". As in my second Image, you can see that the final peak of the blue graph is higher than the orange one. This needs to remain as I am trying to compare the performance of stocks with different scales.

Comment: Right. Your comment made me wonder if your expectation is correct. Because, according to your second image, A overall performance is better than B, but that's not the case (A increase is 200%, B increase is 240%). Are you sure summing pct_change is correct? I've updated my answer with a new scaling approach which is more logical to me at this point. Cheers.